# Connect bot to Minecraft server

Tags: java, bots, minecraft

I am trying to figure out how to connect a bot to a Minecraft server. I want to have it written entirely in Java (this isn't ComputerCraft OR OpenComputers), be able to join the server, move around, place and break blocks, select blocks from a simulated inventory, use chat, have an intuitive and easy-to-use UI, and be simple enough that I can modify it to whatever requirements I would have later. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: This is a very general question, please try and the limit the scope of your question so we can give you a specific answer.

Comment: Are you using computercraft? There are robots (turtle) they can set block and also beaking them... You can program them with LUA

Comment: I could theoretically strip down parts of minecraft, then combine them, but I don't know how to do that, and that would be cheating. I would want to write it myself so I could learn how a minecraft bot works, but every version I tried to replicate was either too complicated, or in a different language. Either I'm too simple of a programmer, or people don't know how to make a simple bot.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you can use Minecraft Coder Pack to create own client and just make additional code/script that will pass interactions to it, like fake keyboard input etc.
Or you can do that on lower level using packets and raw minecraft protocol - and this is much better way to do such stuff. You can understand protocol by reading MCP code and on some pages like http://wiki.vg/Protocol.
Then you would need to implement whole logic that normal client would do, so if you want to make method `moveTo(locationOnMap)` you would need to write whole logic that will find a path and send small move packet around 20 times per second - as you can't just move instantly to such place. On github you can find some basic protocol implementations, but stuff like path-finding and splitting that to valid packets with valid timing you will probably need to do by yourself.

So at the end you just need to create own client for whole game, you can only strip some features you don't need - but you still need to read every packet.

Comment: I now have only a few options: 1. create a client-side mod 2. completely rewrite minecraft in a simpler, easier to understand form, and make a bot for that, a bit like why minetest was made (will go into more detail later) 3. *i cant think of any way to do any of these*